# JavaScript, access json property

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a .json file like this:

```
import single from 'file.json'


{
"id": 4,
"code": 4508099576,
"important": [
            {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "services"
            }
        ]

}
```

I want to access "services" for render it. But the following syntax doesn´t work:

```
<span>Plans: {single.important.name}</span>
```

Comment: I think you need to learn a little more about Javascript, Datatypes, Arrays, Etc before to start to develop with React. `{single.important[i].name}` where `i` is the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

important is an array and you need to access its first object. Your would write

```
<span>Plans: {single.important[0].name}</span>
```

In case if you want to render all the plans within the important array, you would make use of map like

```
<div>{single.important.map((obj) => {
   return  <span key={obj.id}>Plans: {obj.name}</span>
})</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Important is an array. You need to access it with an index ex.

```
single.important[0].name
```